# Cleaner approach of using third party library

Tags: ios, swift

I use JTAppleCalendar in two places, but in the future maybe I will need to use them more. So I wonder what's cleaner approach: in every view controller write code from beginning and thanks to that it is easy to add custom methods or maybe create a seperated class with this calendar data source and delegate and later just create an instance of this class and call all methods in view controllers which need this calendar.

```
 import Foundation
    import JTAppleCalendar
    
    class CalendarReusableClass {
    
        var formatter = DateFormatter()
    
     func setUpCalendar(calendar: JTACMonthView) {
            calendar.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            calendar.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
            
            calendar.visibleDates { (visibleDates) in
                self.setUpViewsOfCalendar(from: visibleDates)
            }
        }
        
        func setUpViewsOfCalendar(from visibleDates: DateSegmentInfo) {
    
            let date = visibleDates.monthDates.first!.date
            
            self.formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
            self.currentDisplayMonthLabel?.text = self.formatter.string(from: date)
    
        }
func handleCellTextColor(view: JTACDayCell?, cellState: CellState) {
        
        // this must be personalized
        
    }

    func handleCellSelected(view: JTACDayCell?, cellState: CellState) {
     
        // This must be personalized for each view controller, because I use here tableViewCell

    }
}
    extension CalendarReusableClass: JTACMonthViewDataSource {
    
        func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView) -> ConfigurationParameters {
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
    
            let startDate = Date().firstDateOfYear()
            let endDate = formatter.date(from: "2021 12 12")!
                    
            let firstDayOfWeek: DaysOfWeek = .monday
        
            let parameteres = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, firstDayOfWeek: firstDayOfWeek)
            
            return parameteres
        }
    
    }
    
    extension CalendarReusableClass: JTACMonthViewDelegate {
        
        func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTACDayCell {
    
    // HERE I NEED USE CUSTOM CELL (I have another cell for each view controller when I use calendar, for example below I use BodyWeightCalendarCell)
    
            let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "bodyWeightCell", for: indexPath) as! BodyWeightCalendarCell
           
            cell.bodyWeightDateLabel.text = cellState.text
           
            handleCellSelected(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
            handleCellTextColor(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
            
            return cell
            }
            
            func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, willDisplay cell: JTACDayCell, forItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) {
                let cell = cell as! BodyWeightCalendarCell
                
                handleCellSelected(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
                handleCellTextColor(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
            }
            
            
            func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTACDayCell?, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
                handleCellSelected(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
                handleCellTextColor(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
                
                //Code for checking if selected value is in dataArray and when it's true, change textValue
                
        //Code for checking if arrayWithWeight contains selectedValue, if it's false, inform a user that there is no save
                
                //Code for changing buttons design
        
                }
            
            func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, didDeselectDate date: Date, cell: JTACDayCell?, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) {
                
                handleCellSelected(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
                handleCellTextColor(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
            }
         
            func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, didScrollToDateSegmentWith visibleDates: DateSegmentInfo) {
                setUpViewsOfCalendar(from: visibleDates)
            }
        }

import JTAppleCalendar
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// properties from storyboard with calendar view
 @IBOutlet weak var calendarBodyWeight: JTACMonthView! 
...

var calendarReusableClass = CalendarReusableClass()

func viewDidLoad() {
self.calendarBodyWeight.dataSource = calendarReusableClass.dataSource
self.calendarBodyWeight.delegate = calendarReusableClass.delegate
}
}
```

With this approach (taking dataSource and delegate from calendarReusableClass) I can create calendar, but I can't custom methods (like handleCellTextColor or handleCellSelected) which need to be custom for each view controller.

So what can I do to make reusable class but with possibility to create custom methods for each view controller and inject them in my reusable class? Or maybe just create every time calendar in each view controller from beginning?

Comment: You could use a custom delegate/datesource for `CalendarReusableClass` where you could customize your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual when you need to make two directional connection, there're two options:

1. Create a `CalendarReusableClassDelegate`, `weak var delegate: CalendarReusableClassDelegate?`, and call it methods
2. Create closure variables for each action, like `var handleCellTextColorHandler: (JTACDayCell?, CellState)?`

If you know that you can pass delegate/handlers to the init and not going to modify it in future, you can make them `let` and non optimal